# Is there a recent solution for moving map(xamarin.forms.maps) inside scrollview?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, maps

I have a scroll view with a map(xamarin.forms.maps) inside it. When we try to move the map, scrollview gets in the way. Looking for a solution, I'm aware that map movement being affected by scroll view is a known issue already but the problem is that I have seen a lot of old solutions and some of them didn't worked for me due to version changes and others are for java. Is there any workaround or real fix to solve this problem with C#/Xamarin?

Comment: This is inherently an issue with having a scrollable surface inside another scrollable surface.  The best suggestion I can make is that when the map has focus, disable the scrollview's scrolling behavior

Comment: @jason I thought in this way that you jave suggeested but looking for a propertie like "IsScrollable" or something like that didnt find anything that could prevent scrollview from scrolling

Comment: I've found dozens of hits when searching "android scrollview prevent scroll".  Have you tried them?  Even if they're written in Java the underlying API is the same and you can easily translate them to C#

Comment: @Jason the most threads has the same solution and I'm having problems with it. I think its better to create a new question with this code and the errors I've find.

Comment: we will just suggest the same solutions unless you tell us what you've tried and what problems you've had with those solutions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For those who are having same problem and are using Xamarin.forms.maps, you can add InputTransparent="True" in ScrollView tag. It solved the problem but creates a new one that was map renderer freezing and duplicating part of map, I could fix it by putting map inside a Frame! Everything works properly now!

Comment: Legend. Thanks :)

Comment: This works in Android and iOS?